# Web.Config versions for .NET framework 4.6.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, configuration, web-config, .net-4.6.1

I have migrated the Web application from .NET framework v3.5 to v4.6.1. Version number got changed to v4.6.1 in project properties and compiled successfully.

But in the Web.Config file, all the references version number still points to v2.0 and v3.5, can you suggest me to find the appropriate version number for each references.

Refer Image:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Anything with System.Web should be 4.0.0.0. 
You can easily figure out yourself by creating brand new .net-4.6.1 Web Application project (you probably want Web Forms) in VS, and check Version on references that are added. 
You can then update your original web config to target new versions. Do not forget to update:

```
 <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" />
```

...
     
        
...

Comment: Thanks Bobo, similarly i can also chage the mscorlib versions to 4.0.0.0?

Comment: <mscorlib>
  <security>
   <policy>
    <PolicyLevel version="1">
     <SecurityClasses>
      <SecurityClass Name="AllMembershipCondition" Description="System.Security.Policy.AllMembershipCondition, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>

Comment: mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 this should work fine